# How to change auto generated meta description by SEO Ultimate plugin using PHP

Tags: php, wordpress

I've got a total of almost 10k pages and i don't want to manually add these meta tags. So the pages were counties and cities and i want them to have a certain meta description.

head.php

```
<?php if(is_page_template('template/cities.php')){ ?>

   <meta name="description" content="content here" />

<?php } ?>
```

So now the concern is i have 2 different meta descriptions and Google will certainly confuse in crawling these pages. I've checked also the plugin documentation but there is no code in overwriting those auto generated meta description.

Comment: You'll need to find some type of filter hook from within that plugin and modify/prevent that meta output. Short of that, you'll have to run some regex replace on the html output, which you should only do as a last resort.

Comment: I'm not familiar with SEO Ultimate, but if I'm looking at the correct code set, there seems to be a filter for `'su_get_postmeta-description'` for singular pages. Can you confirm this is what you're looking for? You should be able to override this value when `is_page_template('template/cities.php')`

Answer (score 0):

@Phil F thanks, i finally get to edit the meta description using this in functions.php

```
function get_metas($metas){
var_dump($metas);
}

add_filter('su_get_postmeta-description', 'get_metas');
add_action('wp_head', 'get_metas');
```

next is some filtering and i'm done